# How to configure jms-bridge?

Tags: jms, wildfly, wildfly-10

Someone can help me to configure a jms-bridge between two different messages broker? In my case i have to let to communicate an activemq message broker (which is running on wildfly 10 instance) and hornetq message broker (running on wildfly 9 instance).

i was trying to configure my standalone-full.xml as follow:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:1.0">
<server name="default">
    <security-setting name="#">
        <role name="guest" delete-non-durable-queue="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" consume="true" send="true"/>
    </security-setting>
    <address-setting name="#" message-counter-history-day-limit="10" page-size-bytes="2097152" max-size-bytes="10485760" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ"/>

    <http-connector name="http-connector" endpoint="http-acceptor" socket-binding="http"/>

    <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput" socket-binding="http">
        <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
    </http-connector>

    <remote-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http"/>
    <remote-connector name="netty-connector" socket-binding="netty"/>
    <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
    <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
    <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
        <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
        <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
    </http-acceptor>
    <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>

    <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
    <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
    <jms-queue name="InvSyncLocalQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/InvSyncLocalQueue"/>
    <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
</server>
<jms-bridge name="transport-bridge" max-batch-time="60000" max-batch-size="5" max-retries="-1" failure-retry-interval="10000" quality-of-service="DUPLICATES_OK">
    <source destination="jms/queue/InvSyncLocalQueue" connection-factory="ConnectionFactory"/>
    <target password="password.123" user="user" destination="jms/queue/InvSyncRemoteQueue" connection-factory="jms/RemoteConnectionFactory">
        <target-context>
            <property name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory"/>
            <property name="java.naming.provider.url" value="http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8081"/>
            <property name="java.naming.security.principal" value="user"/>
            <property name="java.naming.security.credentials" value="password.123"/>
        </target-context>
    </target>
</jms-bridge>
```

have i to know something particular about connectors and acceptors?
do i miss somethings in my configuration?

thanks to everybody.

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: Did you see the configuration here https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Messaging+configuration

Answer (score 0):

Below is the working JMS bridge I have configured on Wildfly 25 server.

`<jms-bridge name="JMSBridge" module="org.apache.activemq.artemis" quality-of-service="ONCE_AND_ONLY_ONCE" failure-retry-interval="1000" max-retries="-1" max-batch-size="1" max-batch-time="100"> <source connection-factory="java:jboss/exported/examin/connectionfactory" destination="java:jboss/exported/examin/ppp/paymentQueue" user="admin" password="admin"/> <target connection-factory="jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" destination="jms/queue/testQueue" user="admin" password="admin"> <target-context> <property name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory"/> <property name="java.naming.provider.url" value="http-remoting://192.168.202.7:6080"/> <property name="java.naming.security.principal" value="admin"/> <property name="java.naming.security.credentials" value="admin"/> <property name="org.jboss.as.naming.lookup.by.string" value="true"/> </target-context> </target> </jms-bridge>`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).